# android and cloud data storage

Tags: android, database, image, cloud, storage

My application needs a database. It is very cheap in size implementation with sqlite, but one of my friends told me that I can store the DB on the cloud, obviously if you put your DB in the cloud you need internet service to get access to the DB but you can store the DB that is from the cloud on the device? So when the user can get the DB from the cloud storage  and automatically 'download' the DB from the cloud to the device to run offline.

**Assuming that I need images (pretty small) for my app is this effective? How? Why?**

I was looking at [www.parse.com](http://www.parse.com) to store my DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data 'is very cheap in size' as you are saying, then I would suggest you to keep it within the application. Keeping dependency on internet is unnecessary as you are saying you want to run application in offline mode.

Comment: thats true... in essence I was thinking in that way plus I need to store some images that maybe with internet will take a little bit to download in my aplication.
Im developing in android of course, but my friend is developing the same aplication in IOS I really dont understand why he decide store the DB in the cloud cz one of our requeriments is that the aplication needs to run offline, thats why my question is ¿you can download the DB from the cloud and run it offline?